# SQL stored procedure parameter without length

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Can I use `varchar` parameters in my stored procedure without declaring its length? For example I would like to declare my stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [TEST] 
    @Domain varchar,
    @Numbers int
AS
 .....
```

It's much easier for me if the stored procedure can automatically detect the parameter length,  in this case if I changed the column length in my table I will not need to go and update all my stored procedures that uses this column.

Thank you,

Comment: Works just fine, if all your `varchar` parameters are only ever **exactly one character** long .....

Comment: By a similar extension, do you want to change `@Numbers int` to `@Numbers bigint` because what if you change your value in the table to be a `bigint` instead of just an `int`? Your existing length values should be realistic upper limits; But think about everything else you have to change when you alter a column to be longer (Foreign Keys, UI, potentially reports), are the stored procs close to being the most difficult and slowest thing to find and update?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you omit the length, it [defaults to one character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).
For example: `varchar` is a synonym for `varchar(1)`.

One way to define the length in one place is a [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx), like:

```
create type Domain from varchar(30) not null;
```

You can then use this new type in other definitions:

```
create procedure TestProcedure @par1 domain as select @par1
go
create table TestTable (col1 domain)
```

However, you can't change the definition of a type without dropping everything that uses it.

In my experience, data length changes are rare, and when they happen, they're easy to refactor manually.  So I'd stick to `varchar(x)` instead of a `type`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing that you're using SQL Server here, in which case you could specify `varchar(max)` rather than specifying a specific length. As [the documentation for SQL Server notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx), an unspecified length is treated as length 1.

Other databases do not exhibit the same behavior. For example, [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html) treats unspecified length as maximum length.

Note that the `varchar(x)` or (ANSI-standard) `character varying(x)` are pretty much compatible across databases.

Comment: +1 Seems that `VARCHAR(MAX)` is really what the OP is asking for